# Celery worker onStart event?

Tags: celery

I've been looking over the Celery 4.3.0 documentation, but I can't find any kind lifecycle events for workers.  Most of the worker management is command line based,  but I need a way to hook a worker start event in code so I can do some customized queue consumer assignments.

Does Celery have such events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Celery dispatches signals on various events. There are 2 signals related to worker init

`worker_init` signal which is dispatched [before the worker is started](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-init).

`worker_process_init` signal which is dispatched in all pool [child processes when they start](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init).

Here is a sample to code to listen to signals.

```
from celery.signals import worker_init, worker_process_init


@worker_init.connect()
def worker_init_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print('worker_init')


@worker_process_init.connect()
def worker_process_init_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print('worker_process_init')
```